# Dumping html source using w3m gives unexpected characters/symbols

Tags: html, http, w3m

As a new user of w3m I am trying to do something basic like:

```
w3m -dump_source nytimes.com > nytimes.html
```

The output produced gives crazy characters and symbols. However, when I browse using `w3m nytimes`, it loads properly, and I can even view the HTML using `v`.

Further when I tried:

```
w3m -dump_extra nytimes.com > nytimes.html
```

I get all the extra info associated with the site perfectly, except for the HTML source.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

By default, *w3m* requests compressed output from the server by sending the following HTTP header:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, bzip, bzip2, deflate
```

The value of the header may vary depending on the version of *w3m*, but the fact is that the latest versions of the program request *compressed* output from the host using `Accept-Encoding` header. You can find out the exact headers with the following command:

```
w3m -dump_source -reqlog nytimes.com > /dev/null
```

The request and response headers will be logged to `~/.w3m/request.log` file.

You can request uncompressed version by overriding the header as follows:

```
w3m -dump_source nytimes.com -o accept_encoding='identity;q=0'
```

Or even

```
w3m -dump_source nytimes.com -o accept_encoding='*;q=0'
```

Alternatively, decompress the output via pipe:

```
w3m -dump_source nytimes.com | gunzip -f
```

The `-f` option causes *gunzip* to copy the input data without change to the standard output, if the input data is not in a format recognized by *gunzip*. According to the documentation, you should also pass `--stdout` option, but the piped command should print the result to standard output even without this option.

Note, the server may respond with content compressed in `bzip2`. In this case, you can pipe the output through `bunzip2 -f` command.

Comment: Thank you very much Ruslan. Everything worked perfectly. A follow up question...is there a way to pause w3m from loading the page source for say 5 seconds. Some websites don't load fast enough to capture the html. Tx.

Comment: @user1311034, do you mean the connect/read timeout? I couldn't find such an option for w3m. If you need to set a timeout, you can use `wget` tool that supports `--timeout`, `--dns-timeout`, `--read-timeout`, and `--connect-timeout` options. If the answer solves the problem, please accept it.